# How can i attach django models data as Excel file and send it as mail with SMTP

Tags: python, django, export-to-excel, email-attachments, django-import-export

i have some data in django models and i want to make excel file from that data and attach it in SMTP as file and send it to target user.
i am also using django-import-export to export the excel files .but in this case i want to attach the file in email.

**Model**

```
class FinalBill(models.Model):
shipDate = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
customerReference = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
customerConfirmation = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
deliveryConfirmation = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
address = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
service = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
weight = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True)
pricingZone = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
uspsCompRate = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True)
charges = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True)
surcharges = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True)
totalSavings = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True)
totalCharges = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True)
customerID = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
is_exported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
exported_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.deliveryConfirmation)
```

**Utills.py**

```
def send_bill_on_mail(mailerID):
   customerBill = FinalBill.objects.filter(customerID=mailerID, is_exported=False)
   dataset = Bills().export(customerBill)
   mail_subject = "Subject Name"
   message = "Test Email Message"
   to_email = "xyz@gmail.com"
   file = "file"        
   mail = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message,  settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [to_email])
   mail.attach(file.name, file.read(), file.content_type)
   mail.send()
```

Comment: What is `dataset` in your `send_bill_on_mail`? What does the `Bill.export` do and return?

Comment: i was trying to export the file and save the file in some directory and then i will  attach that file from that directory to mail .but i have no idea how to do that also...

Comment: but i can export the file with django-import-export but i am stuck at how to attach it in mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def export_data_to_excel(mailerID) -> None: 
  excelfile = BytesIO()
  workbook = Workbook()
  workbook.remove(workbook.active)
  worksheet = workbook.create_sheet(title='Title Name', index=1)

  bill_queryset =  Bills.objects.filter(cus_id=mailerID, is_exported=False)
  columns = ['Date', 'Reference', 'Confirmation', 'Confirmation', 'Address', 'Service', 'Weight', 'Pricing Zone', 'UspsRate', 'Charges', 'Sur Charges', 'Total Savings', 'Total Charges', 'Customer ID']
  row_num = 1

# Assign the titles for each cell of the header
  for col_num, column_title in enumerate(columns, 1):
    cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
    cell.value = column_title
    cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=False)
    cell.font = Font(bold=True)
# Iterate through all coins
 for _, bill in enumerate(bill_queryset, 1):
    row_num += 1

    # Define the data for each cell in the row
    row = [
        bill.shipDate,
        bill.customerReference,
        bill.customerConfirmation,
        bill.deliveryConfirmation,
        bill.address,
        bill.service,
        bill.weight,
        bill.pricingZone,
        bill.uspsCompRate,
        bill.charges,
        bill.surcharges,
        bill.totalSavings,
        bill.totalCharges,
        bill.customerID,
    ]

    # Assign the data for each cell of the row
    for col_num, cell_value in enumerate(row, 1):
        cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
        cell.value = cell_value
        cell.protection = Protection(locked=True)
workbook.save(excelfile)
mail_subject = f'Invoice {mailerID} on {date.today()}'
message = ""
to_email = "xyz@gmail.com"
message = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [to_email])
message.attach(f'Invoice {mailerID}.xlsx', excelfile.getvalue(), 'application/vnd.ms-excel')
message.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

django-tables2 can help you in this, you create your table as Class which will be fed from your data and then you can export the table to XLS document and then you can email to the user.

References:

- [Get Started with django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html)
- [Exporting Data](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/export.html)